# Почему gulp автоматически не обновляет js?

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, gulp, coffeescript

Добрый день!

Подскажите, почему Gulp обновляет кофе только при старте, в процессе работы при изменении файлов кофе ничего не происходит.

gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    jade = require('gulp-jade'),
    stylus = require('gulp-stylus'),
    coffee = require('gulp-coffee'),
    livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    connect = require('connect'),
    serveStatic = require('serve-static'),
    nib = require('nib');


/*
 * Создаём задачи 
 *
 * stylus – для CSS-препроцессора Stylus
 * jade – для HTML-препроцессора Jade
 * coffee – для JavaScript-препроцессора CoffeеScript
 * concat – для склейки всех CSS и JS в отдельные файлы
 */

gulp.task('stylus', function() {
    gulp.src('./styl/*.styl')
        .pipe(stylus({use: nib(), compress: true}))
      .on('error', console.log) // Выводим ошибки в консоль
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css/')) // Выводим сгенерированные CSS-файлы в ту же папку по тем же именем, но с другим расширением
      .pipe(livereload()); // Перезапускаем сервер LiveReload
});

gulp.task('jade', function(){
  gulp.src('./*.jade')
    .pipe(jade({pretty: true}))
    .on('error', console.log) // Выводим ошибки в консоль
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/')) // Выводим сгенерированные HTML-файлы в ту же папку по тем же именем, но с другим расширением
    .pipe(livereload()); // Перезапускаем сервер LiveReload
});

gulp.task('coffee',function(){
  gulp.src('./coffee/*.coffee')
    .pipe(coffee({bare: true}))
    .on('error', console.log) // Выводим ошибки в консоль
     .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js')) // Выводим сгенерированные JavaScript-файлы в ту же папку по тем же именем, но с другим расширением
     .pipe(livereload()); // Перезапускаем сервер LiveReload
});

gulp.task('concat', function(){
  gulp.task('coffee');
  gulp.src('./public/js/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/min/'))
    .pipe(livereload());
  gulp.task('styl');
  gulp.src('./public/css/*.css')
    .pipe(concat('styles.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/min/'))
    .pipe(livereload());
});

gulp.task('imagemin',function(){
   gulp.src('./img/**/*')
        .pipe(imagemin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/img/'));
});

/*
 * Создадим веб-сервер, чтобы работать с проектом через браузер
 */
 gulp.task('server', function() {
    connect()
        .use(require('connect-livereload')())
        .use(serveStatic(__dirname + '/public'))
      .listen('3333');

    console.log('Сервер работает по адресу http://localhost:3333');
});

 /*
  * Создадим задачу, смотрящую за изменениями
  */
 gulp.task('watch', function(){
      livereload.listen();
        gulp.watch('./styl/*.styl',['stylus']);
        gulp.watch('./*.jade',['jade']);
        gulp.watch('./coffee/*.coffee',['coffee']);
        gulp.watch(['./public/js/*.js','./public/css/*.css'],['concat']);
        gulp.watch('./img/**/*',['imagemin']);
      gulp.start('server');
  });

 gulp.task('default',['watch','stylus','jade','coffee','concat','imagemin']);
```

Comment: Из вашего вопроса не ясно какую команду вы запускаете. Я бы сказал что вам нужно запускать `gulp watch`

Comment: Я запускаю Gulp команду watch стоит в default.

Comment: Может просто падает сборка вотчера.

Comment: styl и jade работает

Comment: Дай фотку своей структуры проекта.

Answer (score 1):

Использование gulp-watch решает проблему:

```
var
   gulp = require('gulp'),
   watch = require('gulp-watch');

// Watcher
gulp.task('watch', function() {
   watch('./views/**/*', function() { gulp.start('views') });
   watch('./styl/**/*', function() { gulp.start(['css', 'views']) });
   watch('./js/**/*', function() { gulp.start(['js', 'js-embded']) });
   watch('./js/contact.js', function() { gulp.start('browserify') });
   watch('./img/**/*', function() { gulp.start(['imagemin', 'webp']) });
   watch('./img/favicons/**/*', function() { gulp.start('favicons') });
   watch('./fonts/**/*', function() { gulp.start(['iconfont', 'fonts']) });
   watch('./seo/**/*', function() { gulp.start('seo') });
});
```

Comment: или можно перейти на gulp-4, в нем нормальный ватчер.

Comment: @DimenSi а где вы видите Gulp 4? помоему последняя версия 3.9.1

Comment: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/tree/4.0

Comment: @DimenSi так это не релиз. Альфа только.

Comment: и что? Он в альфа версии был стабильным, а сейчас ему убрали приставку.

Comment: @DimenSi, если не поместили в главный репозиторий, значит, ещё не сочли за стабильный, мне кажется.